# Parse object where values of keys are array of object and remove object using conditions

Tags: node.js, arrays, object, parsing

I have an Object where each key is an Character name and its property is an array of objects with some infos, like below:

```
const x = {
  'Dr. Hank Pym': [
    {
      actor: 'Michael Douglas',
      character: 'Dr. Hank Pym',
      title: 'Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania',
      release_date: '2023-07-26'
    },
    {
      actor: 'Michael Douglas',
      character: 'Dr. Hank Pym',
      title: 'Avengers: Endgame',
      release_date: '2019-04-24'
    }
  ],
  'Cassie Lang': [
    {
      actor: 'Kathryn Newton',
      character: 'Cassie Lang',
      title: 'Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania',
      release_date: '2023-07-26'
    },
    {
      actor: 'Emma Fuhrmann',
      character: 'Cassie Lang',
      title: 'Avengers: Endgame',
      release_date: '2019-04-24'
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to check if in an Character, all the actors are the same, and if yes, remove this character. In this example the response would be

```
const respose = 'Cassie Lang': [
        {
          actor: 'Kathryn Newton',
          character: 'Cassie Lang',
          title: 'Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania',
          release_date: '2023-07-26'
        },
        {
          actor: 'Emma Fuhrmann',
          character: 'Cassie Lang',
          title: 'Avengers: Endgame',
          release_date: '2019-04-24'
        }
      ]
```

I tried to use Array.every, but only received true or false response

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will look through an array of objects and see if one particular property has the same value for every object in the array:

```
function allSame(array, prop) {
    let allSame = true;
    let value;
    for (const [index, item] of array.entries()) {
        if (index === 0) {
            value = item[prop];
        } else {
            if (item[prop] !== value) {
                allSame = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return allSame;
}
```

Or, done a little less efficiently, you could do use this for the `allSame()` function:

```
function allSame(array, prop) {
    const set = new Set(array.map(item => item[prop]));
    return set.size < 2;
}
```

Note, this function is literal.  It will return `true` if the array has length 0 or 1 (since all values of the property are the same) or even if all objects in the array don't even contain that property (since all values of that property are `undefined`).  You can add a few checks to avoid those special cases if you want.

Then, to use this function, you just iterate the properties of your object and call this function on each array like this:

```
for (let [character, array] of Object.entries(x)) {
    if (allSame(array, "actor")) {
        delete x[character];
    }
}
```

Putting that together into a working snippet where you can run it, you get this:

```js
const x = {
    'Dr. Hank Pym': [{
            actor: 'Michael Douglas',
            character: 'Dr. Hank Pym',
            title: 'Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania',
            release_date: '2023-07-26'
        },
        {
            actor: 'Michael Douglas',
            character: 'Dr. Hank Pym',
            title: 'Avengers: Endgame',
            release_date: '2019-04-24'
        }
    ],
    'Cassie Lang': [{
            actor: 'Kathryn Newton',
            character: 'Cassie Lang',
            title: 'Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania',
            release_date: '2023-07-26'
        },
        {
            actor: 'Emma Fuhrmann',
            character: 'Cassie Lang',
            title: 'Avengers: Endgame',
            release_date: '2019-04-24'
        }
    ]
}

function allSame(array, prop) {
    let allSame = true;
    let value;
    for (const [index, item] of array.entries()) {
        if (index === 0) {
            value = item[prop];
        } else {
            if (item[prop] !== value) {
                allSame = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return allSame;
}

for (let [character, array] of Object.entries(x)) {
    if (allSame(array, "actor")) {
        delete x[character];
    }
}

console.log(x);
```

Comment: @rafaelpolonio - Does this answer it for you?